# Need Fix For That Error { Redirect URI must be absolute }

Tags: redirect, uri, absolute

```java
public function setRedirectUri($uri)
{
    if (is_null($uri)) {
        $this->redirectUri = null;

        return;
    }
    // redirect URI must be absolute
    if (!$this->isAbsoluteUri($uri)) {
        // "postmessage" is a reserved URI string in Google-land
        // @see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow
        if ('postmessage' !== (string)$uri) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Redirect URI must be absolute');
        }
    }
    $this->redirectUri = (string)$uri;
}
```

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: InvalidArgumentException

Message: Redirect URI must be absolute

Filename: /home/fhnm4mkw4lqa/public_html/application/third_party/google-api-client/vendor/google/auth/src/OAuth2.php

Line Number: 745
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  `if (!$this->isAbsoluteUri($uri))` condition only proceeds if the entered URL is not absolute, however, ignoring that part, I was able to solve my error the following way:

My URL was formatted like this and I was getting this exact same error:
`localhost/CalculatorApp/redirectTest`

Now all I had to do was add `http://` in front of the URL so it would look like this:
`http://localhost/CalculatorApp/redirectTest`

I was using Google API as well and this solved my issue.